# Updating ui_bookmark Table When Adding Columns via ui_component XML

Tags: magento2, xml, uicomponent

In Magento 2, the `ui_component` based grids allow you to reorder columns and Magento will remember your settings the next time you log in.  This is accomplished by Magento saving data in the `ui_bookmark` table (via a `Magento\Ui\Model\Bookmark` model object).

While this feature it neat, it can create problems when a extension developer or system integrator uses Magento `ui_component` XML to add columns to a table.  If there's a custom data `ui_bookmark` then Magento will (seemingly) ignore the sort order of a new column and weird/unexpected things can happen.

Is there a best practice and/or system for extension developers who want to add columns to a UI Grid (either Magento's or their own) and ensure a column is somewhere in relation to the others?  i.e. -- "This second action button should always appear last, or always appear second last", or "the name field should always be after ID.

Does an extension developer need to, via an `app/code/Package/Module/Setup/...` class, reach into the `ui_bookmark` table and update these entries themselves?  Or is there a better way to accomplish this?  Or do extension developers just need to live with a column being added to unexpected places when a user already has an entry in `ui_bookmark`?

Answer (score 5):

I think that this is bug in magento2.

I usually clean ui_bookmark table after adding new columns by any modules.

Magento2 save columns positions even if there are no any modification in columns ordering.

```
"positions":{
    "ids":0,
    "increment_id":1,
    "store_id":2,
    "created_at":3,
    "billing_name":4,
    "shipping_name":5,
    ...
}
```

But if columns positions will be stored only after user modifications, we will have same problem with new columns.

If will be added relative ordering like as `name column after id` or `my_column before actions`, we will have ugly dragging of columns in UI.

If you will clear `ui_bookmark` table during module installation - you can clear custom user settings for the listing.

Maybe, core developers need to fix actions column as last as partial solution.

I think, that this question has not the only right decision