# How to remove/hide columns from sales grid by default

Tags: magento2, attributes, sales-order, order-grid, column

How can I remove or hide some of the columns from sales_order_grid. For example I want to hide next columns:

1. Purchase point
2. Ship to Name
3. Signifyd Guarantee Decision

I tried with overriding sales_order_grid and adding visibility attribute as false, but nothing happened.

I want to hide them in Default View, and not to create new View with those columns disabled.

Thank you

Comment: Hi! Did you clean a cache?

Comment: Yes, i am cleaning cache and static files after every change.

Answer (score 4):

You need to override

> sales_order_grid.xml

as you said. Put this code into your module, file view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 *
 * file <Vendor>/<Module name>/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="store_id" class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Purchase Point</label>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <sortable>false</sortable>
                <visible>false</visible>
                <controlVisibility>false</controlVisibility>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="shipping_name">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Ship-to Name</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
                <controlVisibility>false</controlVisibility>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="signifyd_guarantee_status" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <options class="Magento\Signifyd\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Guarantee\Options"/>
                <visible>false</visible>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Signifyd Guarantee Decision</label>
                <controlVisibility>false</controlVisibility>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

But, this only work for newly created users. For existing users, you need to truncate table *ui_bookmark* as you can see on [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178958/magento2-where-the-admin-console-user-preferences-stored/178961#178961)

For a detailed explanation, you can check [following](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142112/updating-ui-bookmark-table-when-adding-columns-via-ui-component-xml)

My suggestion is to put that in UpgradeData file, for example

```
<?php

namespace <Vendor>\<Module name>\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

/**
 * Data upgrade script
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) {
            // Empty ui_bookmark table, so that new column's settings take power.
            $setup->getConnection()->truncateTable(
                $setup->getTable('ui_bookmark')
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide columns from grid page.

see screenshot

[image]

Just you have to check/uncheck those checkbox.

Thanks

Comment: As I said, I want to hide them in Default View, not to create new one. 
I want to remove that columns for all users so they don't need to do that manually like you say.